# Google Sheets: "Text to Columns", but in single column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a huge data file.  Each line may contain one or more entries separated by a pipe:

```
one|two|three
alpha
uno|dos
beta
gamma
```

I can use "Text to Columns" to remove the `|` and put each entry in its own column:

```
one     two     three
alpha
uno     dos
beta
gamma
```

But my desired result is to have all items in a single column:

```
one
alpha
uno
beta
gamma
two
three
dos
```

How can I easily get all entries into a single column?  (order does NOT matter)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A:Z), "|"))), "where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: it seems you're not worried about warning folks that there's something weird about Flatten() in that it's undocumented?  i feel like we should warn people that it could get deprecated, no?

Comment: well, if ggl dudes will remove it, we still have query/transpose/query/transpose combo :) tho that is undocumented as well

Comment: well we will!, but not the folks we've helped with flatten()...

Answer (score 0):

Assume Range A1:A5 is your data

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("|",A1:A5),"|"))
```

> `JOIN` them to add `"|"` to all of them first
>
> then `SPLIT` text that has `"|"` to be 1 row, many columns
>
> then `TRANSPOSE` to get just one column going

This is the basic one I can think of, anyways there are a lot of ways to do this

Comment: If it is a huge data file. this formula may hit the 50,000 character limit of the JOIN function.